# Integrate a weighted Bessel function over the unit disk

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, bessel-functions, approximate-integration

I would like to evaluate a complex-valued integral of the form

$$
I_e = \int_0^1 x e^{iax} J_0(b \sqrt{1-x^2}) dx
$$

where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers (not necessarily positive) and $J_0(z)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.

An alternative statement of the problem can be considered by making a change of variables $z=b\sqrt{1-x^2}, c = a/b$, so that

$$
I_e = \frac{1}{b^2} \int_0^b z e^{ic\sqrt{b^2-z^2}} J_0(z) dz.
$$

I am particularly interested in the special case of $0\leq b \leq 100$ with $c = 1$ or $-4 \leq c \leq -1$.

The task boils down to evaluating two real-valued integrals

$$
I_s = \frac{1}{b^2} \int_0^b z \sin(c\sqrt{b^2-z^2}) J_0(z) dz
$$
$$
I_c = \frac{1}{b^2} \int_0^b z \cos(c\sqrt{b^2-z^2}) J_0(z) dz
$$

The integral with the sine has a simple form given by [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (6.738.1)](https://books.google.com/books?id=NjnLAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA749&lpg=PA749&dq=Bessel+and+trigonometric+functions+and+powers+6.738&source=bl&ots=I_tCYsGog9&sig=ACfU3U0h_PrVut9BI6Y9ZlBgUFhkfhHGTw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiB1qaxlJLqAhXiMn0KHVPoBrEQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ) which, after simplification, becomes

$$
I_s = c \frac{j_1(b\sqrt{c^2 + 1})}{\sqrt{c^2 + 1}} = a \frac{j_1(\sqrt{a^2 + b^2})}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}
$$

where $j_1(z)$ is the spherical Bessel function of the first kind.

I am not exactly sure how this expression was derived. Perhaps it holds a clue. I tried substituting the [integral form](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9) of the Bessel function and integrating analytically but did not get very far.

By symmetry, I naively expected the integral involving the cosine to be proportional to the spherical Bessel function of the second kind $y_1(z)$ (and thus, the complex-valued integral to be proportional to the spherical Hankel function of the second kind), but that does not appear to be the case.

$$
I_c \neq -c \frac{y_1(b\sqrt{c^2 + 1})}{\sqrt{c^2 + 1}}
$$

Particularly, because of the cosine term inside the Bessel function,

$$ \lim_{b\to0} I_c \neq \lim_{b\to0} -c \frac{y_1(b\sqrt{c^2 + 1})}{\sqrt{c^2 + 1}}$$

A better approximation can be achieved by dropping the cosine part of the spherical Bessel

$$
I_c \approx c \frac{\sin(b\sqrt{c^2 + 1})}{b(c^2 + 1)}
$$

Indeed, if we plot $I_c \times b$, we can see that it is a regular sine wave for $b \geq 4$. My current goal is to find a correction term (via a series expansion, perhaps) that would improve the approximation for $b < 4$.

[image: plot]

I've only found a single identity connected to the approximation given above. [Tables of Integral Transforms](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/), Vol. 2, p. 337, eq. 29 gives

$$
\int_0^b \frac{z}{\sqrt{b^2-z^2}} \cos(c\sqrt{b^2-z^2}) J_0(z) dz =  \frac{\sin(b\sqrt{c^2 + 1})}{\sqrt{c^2 + 1}}
$$

I am not sure what's the best way to connect this identity to $
I_c$. The two integrals only differ by the first term (and the constant $
1/b^2$). One way is to perform a Taylor expansion around the origin:

$$\frac{z}{\sqrt{b^2-z^2}} = \frac{z}{b} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^3}{b^3} + O(z^5) $$

The left part is from the identity, and the first term on the right is from $I_c$. The cubic term does not appear to help, so perhaps this is not the right expansion to use in this case (and perhaps I should expand at infinity rather than at the origin).

I would appreciate any tips or guidance. Thank you!

Comment: I took a look at the Bateman project's tables. It seems that there is an explicit representation of the sine transform iff the sine is multiplied by an odd power of $x$ and there is an explicit representation of the cosine transform iff the cosine is multiplied by an even power of $x$.

Comment: Thanks, Gary! I am taking a look. Currently, I am trying to find some kind of expansion that features a spherical Bessel function of the second kind, since it is clearly a good match for large values of the argument. Perhaps that would allow me to find a correction term.

Comment: Perhaps it could be integrated by parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an evaluation of $I_s$, start with
$$I_e = \int_0^1 x e^{iax} J_0(b \sqrt{1-x^2}) dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin x \cos x e^{ia\cos x} J_0(b\sin x) dx$$
It is known that (proved easily by using series expansion of $J_\mu$ and beta function):
$$J_{\nu+\mu+1}(z) = \frac{z^{\nu+1}}{2^\nu \Gamma(\nu+1)} \int_0^{\pi/2} J_\mu(z\sin x) \sin^{\mu+1}x \cos^{2\nu+1} x dx$$
Therefore taking imaginary part gives
$$I_s = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}{a^{2n + 1}}}}{{(2n + 1)!}}{J_{n + 3/2}}(b)\frac{{{2^{n + 1/2}}\Gamma (n + 3/2)}}{{{b^{n + 3/2}}}}}  = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{2}} a\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - {a^2}/2)}^n}}}{{n!}}\frac{{{J_{n + 3/2}}(b)}}{{{b^{n + 3/2}}}}} $$
Now use equation $(1)$ proved in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3575900/257943), we complete the proof:
$$I_s  = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{2}} a\frac{{{J_{3/2}}(\sqrt {{a^2} + {b^2}} )}}{{{{({a^2} + {b^2})}^{3/4}}}}$$

---

Real part of $I_e$ gives
$$I_c = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}{a^{2n}}}}{{(2n)!}}{J_{n + 1}}(b)\frac{{{2^n}n!}}{{{b^{n + 1}}}}} $$
I don't think this can be expressed in terms of Bessel-related functions only, but note that the summand decrease very rapidly (due to $n!/(2n)!$ and also $J_{n+1}(b)$), so this might be useful if you're interested in numerical calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the derivation! I really appreciate it. I need to look further into series expansions.
Your solution works, but the convergence rate is not particularly good. Please see for yourself: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bIL_VREAPWRRFzkKpyIiwI5VEzULt4ab/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I plotted your series solution limited to the first 10 terms (in orange) versus the reference (in blue) versus another approximation which is roughly $\sin(a)/a$. Your solution is superbly accurate up until $a=10$, where it numerically explodes. The sine, on the other hand, is pretty good starting from $a=10$ to infinity (but is off for small values). This makes me wonder whether the sine-based solution can be extended for small values. Unfortunately, using an arbitrarily large number of terms is not really feasible for my application.

Comment: @zalbard Since the series involves $a^{2n}$, such behavior is usual for large $a$. What range of $a,b$ you want to approximate $I_c$? It seems you want to do this when $a$ is large, and $b$ can be both large and small?

Comment: I updated the question with these details. I also added a graph, as well as another identity I found in the literature.